# using paste in R to concatenate a command

Tags: r

I have the below code to extract a named number from the class term_strc_nss.  it works fine extracts the values for the beta vector and passes them along to the next function.  However, the trade date which is `2012-12-31` and defines the slot in the class changes.  So, I need to pass trade date as a variable into the code.

```
BetaVector <<- unname(term.structure$opt_result$`2012-12-31`$par[c("beta0",
"beta1","beta2", "tau1")])
```

The code below uses paste but when I run the function I get errors that seem to be related to the quote marks around the "beta0", "beta1", "beta2" and "tau1".  I tried replacing the " with ' I can run the code but then the value was not passed because the beta vector is just a string of names.

```
BetaVector <<- paste("unname(term.structure$opt_result$`",tradedate,"`$par[c("beta0",
"beta1", "beta2", "tau1")])")
```

I guess I could create a method to extract the Beta coefficients but I will still face the same problem when creating the method.  Is there a better way to extract a named number from a class?

Here is the dput from the term.structure.  term.structure is an object termstrc_nss and is an S3 class what is the proper way to refer to it?

```
structure(list(`2012-12-31` = structure(list(par = structure(c(3.41273726187976, 
-2.63342593294169, -5.34244663887461, 2.13363495349724), .Names = c("beta0", 
"beta1", "beta2", "tau1")), value = 0.0088680383803467, counts = structure(c(15, 
 10), .Names = c("function", "gradient")), convergence = 0L, message = NULL, 
outer.iterations = 2L, barrier.value = -0.000409627261066452), .Names = c("par", 
"value", "counts", "convergence", "message", "outer.iterations", 
"barrier.value"))), .Names = "2012-12-31")
```

Comment: Post `dput(term.structure$opt_result)`, and please do not use the term 'slot' when not referring to S4 structures. There is quite a bit that remains ambiguous in this question and you are at risk for attracting close votes if you don't have code and data that lines up with the textual description and question.

Comment: The answer to this question seems to be escape your quotes: `\"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do some sort of eval-parse technique.  This is almost always a bad idea since it makes your code nearly impossible to debug.  Use square bracket indexing instead.

```
trade_date <- "2012-12-31"
BetaVector <<- unname(
  term.structure$opt_result[[trade_date]]$par[c("beta0","beta1","beta2", "tau1")]
)
```

Comment: Thanks Richie, I used term.structure$opt_result[[1]]$par[c("beta0", "beta1", "beta2", "tau1")].  That works, I guess I could do that across the entire class I will have to think of a way to control to make sure I am grabbing the right output - but this get me going ahead.